# php URI troube with if statement,

Tags: php, url, codeigniter, conditional-statements, uri

I am running an if statement, that looks like this,

```
if($this->uri->segment(1) !== 'search' || $this->uri->segment(1) !== 'employment') {
    //dome something
}
```

My problem is that first condition works, if the uri segment 1 equals search then the method do not run however if I on the page employment, and the first segment of the uri is employment then the condition still runs, why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this i think:

```
if($this->uri->segment(1) === 'search' || $this->uri->segment(1) === 'employment') {
    //dome something
}
```

Use `===` instead of `!==`

Answer (score 2):

you have to do

```
if($this->uri->segment(1) === 'search' || $this->uri->segment(1) === 'employment') {
    //do something
}
```

or

```
if($this->uri->segment(1) !== 'search' && $this->uri->segment(1) !== 'employment') {
    //do something
}
```

depending on what you want to do... asking for `(bla!=blubb || bla!=blah)` doen't make any sense because it will be true everytime.